# Problems loading resource into java application from filesystem

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, nullpointerexception, imageicon

I'm trying to set an image icon on a label on NetBeans (for Mac).
I set the image after imported it in the project folder:
[screenshot of selected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emzji.png)

When I try to run the project it fails with these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at Laboratorio.Login.initComponents(Login.java:52)
at Laboratorio.Login.<init>(Login.java:17)
at Laboratorio.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Login.java:52:

```
labelLogo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Laboratorio/Immagini/logo_550.png")));
```

The path of the image is:
/Users/salvatore/NetBeansProjects/Laboratorio/src/main/java/Laboratorio/Immagini/logo_550.png

Can someone help me, please?
Thanks!

Comment: It must be in your class path, not your file system.

Comment: The simplest solution, in my opinion, is to copy file `logo_550.png` to the same folder as file `Login.java` and change the java code to `getClass().getResource("logo_550.png")`

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Now it's in the class path, but same errors.

Comment: @Abra Ok I changed the code but same errors too

Comment: then it is not in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.
I was using Java with Gradle (never used)... I always used Java with Ant. Now it works correctly with the same code.